# What to do when JAVA server(PC) sends message to a wrong Android client through Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

I am working on an app where a server (PC) accepts and processes Android client requests through Bluetooth. I've created individual threads for the connected clients. However, when (for example) Client A asks for the next data from the server, the server sends the data to Client B.

Here's my code snippet for the server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
    System.out.println("Address: "+localDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
    System.out.println("Name: "+localDevice.getFriendlyName());
    UUID uuid = new UUID("1101", true);

    String connectionString = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid +";name=Sample SPP Server";

    StreamConnectionNotifier streamConnNotifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier)Connector.open( connectionString );

    System.out.println("\nServer Started. Waiting for clients to connect...");

    while(true){
         ClientClass c = new ClientClass(streamConnNotifier.acceptAndOpen(), id);
         id++;
         clientList.add(c);
         Thread t = new Thread(c);
         t.start();  
    }
}
```

ClientClass declaration code:

```
public class ClientClass implements Runnable {
 private final StreamConnection _connection;
 private final int _id;

 public ClientClass(StreamConnection connection, int id){
    this._connection = connection;
    this._id = id;
 }

 public void run()
{
    try {

        RemoteDevice dev = RemoteDevice.getRemoteDevice(this._connection);
        System.out.println("Remote device address: "+dev.getBluetoothAddress());
        devName = dev.getFriendlyName(true);

        inStream = this._connection.openInputStream();
        outStream = this._connection.openOutputStream();

    while(true){
        BufferedReader bReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        String lineRead=bReader.readLine();
        System.out.println(lineRead);
        questionInit.checkAnswer(lineRead);
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: ClientClass is missing the run() method

Comment: Okay. I edited my code, however that's not the only code written inside the run() method. And disregard other method like checkAnswer() of questionInit